# Loading a javascript module stored on IPFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, ipfs

Let's say I have javascript files on IPFS, for example, [this](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmc4qYx6TpTjAzCjW7E4zyasoFQzVbcPW8xvUCqfYZmKLA). I want to build a piece of javascript (node) code that will retrieve the ipfs hash, and will then have to load the file(s) pointed to. So far I'm doing:

```
node.get(fileHash, (err, files) => {
    // some check for error
    files
    .filter(file => file.type === 'file')
    .forEach(file => {
        vm.runInThisContext(
            code    = file.content.toString('utf8'),
            options = { filename: file.name }
        );
    });
});
```

I don't really want to mess up with the filesystem (this will have to run in a browser) so I'd like to avoid writing the files and then requiring them.

Is there a better way to load javascript code that is stored in a variable (basically). I feel like I'm using some sort of `eval` ... which I don't like

Answer (score 3):

You could load the modules from the IPFS HTTP Gateway

```
<script src="https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<cid>/mything.js" />
```

If the user has [ipfs-companion](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-companion) installed, the resource will be fetched from the users local ipfs gateway at `localhost:8080`, and if not it will be fetched from the public gateway at `ipfs.io`. This could be interesting with es modules and import flavour

```
import foo from https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<cid>/index.js`
```

If you want to load the resources with [js-ipfs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) as in your example, then you can use `[ipfs.cat][2]` to get the response instead of `ipfs.get`. You'll have to do some form of `eval` as you didnt ask the browser to fetch the script

```
// get the script
const data = await ipfs.cat('CidForYourScript')

// depending on how your script is packaged, eval it
const exports = (new Function(data.toString()))()
```

See this PR on js-ipfs for more discussion of this idea from the core developers: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/pull/1830

For more ideas on eval-ing js see: https://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/